# Using Conservation of momentum and Energy to solve a problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

A 9kg bullet is fired horizontally into a 10 kg block of wood suspended by a rope from the ceiling. The block swings in an arc, rising 6mm above its lowest position. Find the velocity of the bullet.

Well,this is what I have so far:

1. Conservation of momentum 
   $$ 
       M_b \times v_b=(M_b+M_w)v                     
       $$
2. Conservation of energy 
   $$ 
       5(M_b+M_w)v^2=(M_w+M_b) 
       $$

I'm a nontraditional student trying to grasp these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [inelastic collision](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/inecol.html#c2) (the bullet and wood do not elastically bounce off of each other but instead, 'stick' together) and so, *kinetic* energy is not conserved in the collision.

However, the total momentum just *before* the collision must equal the total momentum just *after* the collision.

$$p(0-) = m_b v_b = p(0+) = (m_b + m_w)v_{bw}$$

Thus, the kinetic energy $T$ just after the collision is

$$T(0+) = \frac{1}{2}(m_b + m_w)v^2_{bw}$$

Now, the bullet/wood combination then trades all of that initial kinetic energy for potential energy $U$ at the top of the swing so it must be that

$$\Delta U = T(0+)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so...The equation I use to solve is Vb=(Mw+Mb)/(Mb)*(2gh)^1/2?

Comment: @user175623, that looks correct to me.

Comment: I appreciate the input